# Cannot delete private beta account

Tags: support, bug, deleted-accounts, private-beta

I'd like to delete my private beta account on world building.
However, the delete link on the profile page is not there.
Is this a bug or is it intentional?

Comment: have you participated in the site? Asking questions, voted, answering questions, etc?

Comment: I can confirm ton has participated in the site.

Comment: Not a bug, you should request account deletion in the ordinary way like you do it on any other site. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account), under "If you have voted or posted, please contact the Stack Exchange Team".

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh i see, I just skimmed that page and saw the screenshot, successfully deleted a few other accounts and was wondering why it was different. Thanks.